# Why find_one is returning all documents in my case?

Tags: python, eve

I'm trying to use BCryptAuth to protect resource as well as for login system.
I'm trying to fetch only one document based on user's email entered at login page.

```
class BCryptAuth(BasicAuth):
def check_auth(self, email, password, allowed_roles, resource, method):
    account = app.data.driver.db['users'].find_one({'email': email})
    return account and \
            bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'),account['salt'].encode('utf-8')) == account['password']
```

But when i try to access the users end point via postman, it actually authenticates but returns all documents. I'm bit confused. If my approach is wrong, pls provide me one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Auth class you mention will only allow or not the access to the API. It does nothing for resource filtering.

If you want resource filtering when getting `users`, you can create an event hook and make a pre-GET dynamic filter. Check the [documentation](http://python-eve.org/features.html#dynamic-lookup-filters), it should help.